# Corporate VPN internet traffic tracing

Tags: remote-desktop, vpn

When using a VPN to connect to a corporate computer, the traffic would typically pass through some VPN server inside the company.

Is there a way to know if all traffic goes through there or only the remote desktop application traffic?

Assuming they trace the webpages you visited, for how long would they store them before deleting? I'm assuming they are going to delete after a while.

Comment: Waht VPN client are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If your connected to a VPN, you can look at your routing table on your local machine to find out what traffic goes through that connection. Its pretty advanced stuff but but I'll try to give a quick example:

The IP address of your computer on your home network is 192.168.1.12
The IP address of your computer on your companies vpn network is 10.10.1.23

if your routing table looks something like this

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.12    10
     10.0.0.0         255.0.0.0      10.10.1.1       10.10.1.23      25
    127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
```

the 0.0.0.0 network destination means ALL traffic is going through the 192.168.1.1 interface (meaning your home network in this example). BUT, any traffic destined for a 10. whatever address is going through your VPN. So take note if your routing table says something like

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.10.1.1       10.10.1.23      25
    127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1      306
    127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1      306
```

because that means that ALL your network traffic is now being routed through the vpn. VPNs do have the ability to change routing tables b/c they need to, just an FYI.

If you're using windows you can find your IP addresses by opening a command prompt and typing ipconfig /all

you can view your current routing table by typing route print at the same command prompt.

What Simkill said about web page logging is correct also.

Comment: is there a "Terms and Condition" I can look at, at least for typical Corporate VPN providers?

Comment: You can ask your IT Department for their policy, it's controlled by them. Also, they may have a Service Level Agreement that it might be written into, and also an Acceptable Use Policy doesn't hurt to get so you know the Dos and Donts.

Comment: Please mark as answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no definitive answer for your last point on web page logging, that'll be down to the companies data retention policy. You can do a tracert in cmd from your laptop to google to see if it bounces off vpn server or internal interface of your companies router, depending on what you're connecting too. That'll depend if the VPN configuration is set to point the gateway (vpn server) as the default route for everything, or just create a new route for the companies network address.